# How to use MVVM with SwiftUI correctly?

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui

I'm currently learning about the use of MVVM and SwiftUI, and I was wondering, are the View allowed to pass Model objects to the ViewModel?

Example:

At one point while I was coding, I needed to use one variable from an object in a view, So i created a ViewModel to only pass that one variable, by doing something like this:

```swift
struct ListRowView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()
    let modelData: ModelData;

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(viewModel.name)
        }.onAppear() {
            self.viewModel.fetchData(modelData: self.modelData)
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var title = "";

    func fetchData(modelData: ModelData){
        self.title = modelData.title;
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way of using MVVM and SwiftUI? Because in this example the view technacly handles a Model object by passing it to the ViewModel? Is this "okay?" or is other solutions better? and in that case, which?

Comment: For me, your approach seems neat. Not for showing-off, but you could check [this example](https://github.com/alekseypotapov-dev/GithubHeartSwift).  I did some time ago in MVVM-ish. I also didn't find any else solution about how to pass the models without View.

Comment: First of all, the View shouldn't be creating the ViewModel for itself. You should be injecting the ViewModel into the view. Secondly, how is `ModelData` initialised? In any case, the view should not be creating any models at all - if you need to bind user input to your models, use one of the property wrappers, like `@State` or `@Binding` to do so.